# [error]Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy

Tags: maven, deployment

I've created Maven-project in Intellij Idea and with trying to deploy of application, i've got an error. Help me to solve this problem, please.

```
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project Er-Fly: Deployment failed: repository element was not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement element or in -DaltDeploymentRepository=id::layout::url parameter -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: run the command with -X switch as recommended in output. This will spit out the whole stacktrace, which will make it easier to figure out the problem.

Comment: Which command are you running? It does look like you're trying to push artefacts to a remote repository (distribution management). As it seems to be the case then @Rocologo answer is the correct one.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that you have the **repository** element in the **distributionManegement** defined:

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>plugins-releases</name>
        <url>http://serverip:8081/artifactory/plugins-release-local</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <name>plugins-snapshot</name>
        <url>http://serverip:8081/artifactory/plugins-snapshot-local</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

Also check that the username in your in maven .m2/settings.yml file has permission to PUT (upload) files to the artifactory.

Answer (score -1):

The error is here : `repository element was not specified in the POM`. See  http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Repositories to add the element.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                      https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  ...
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <releases>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
        <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
        <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
      </snapshots>
      <id>codehausSnapshots</id>
      <name>Codehaus Snapshots</name>
      <url>http://snapshots.maven.codehaus.org/maven2</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    ...
  </pluginRepositories>
  ...
</project>
```